# Why is std::pair<A,B> not the same as std::tuple<A,B>? (Is there really no way?)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, tuples

Why is `std::pair<A,B>` not the same as `std::tuple<A,B>`? It always felt strange to not be able to just substitute one with the other. They are somewhat convertible, but there are limitations.

I know that `std::pair<A,B>` is required to have the two data members `A first` and `B second`, so it can't be just a type alias of `std::tuple<A,B>`. But my intuition says that we could specialize `std::tuple<A,B>`, that is a tuple with exactly two elements, to equal the definition of what the standard requires a `std::pair` to be. And then alias this to `std::pair`.

I guess this wouldn't be possible as it is too straight-forward to not to be already thought of, yet it wasn't done in g++'s libstdc++ for example (I didn't look at the source code of other libraries). What would the problem of this definition be? Is it "just" that it would break the standard library's binary compatibility?

Comment: Possibly because of implementation limitations (tuples are implemented recursively, either by having a subobject of shorter tuple type or inheriting from it). Each tuple of size >=3 would wind up with those members somwhere in it.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot  Hmm good point... But what about some recursive `tuple_impl` (in the way the current tuple is implemented), then alias `tuple = tuple_impl` for 0, 1 and >=3 elements, but `tuple = pair_impl<A,B>` for 2 elements as well as `pair = tuple<A,B>`. I hope you understand this. Basically another alias indirection, hiding the recursive implementation details.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Modern `tuple` implementations are not recursive.

Comment: I sketched the above idea [here](http://ideone.com/oP57sg) (Not to be meant to compile...)

Comment: Using an alias breaks code that specializes `std::pair` (which you are allowed to do for user-defined types).

Comment: @leemes: I mean there are some obvious historical issues. `std::pair` is used by `std::map` which has been part of C++ since the stoneage. `std::tuple` is new since C++11. Another issue is that if they were *literally* the same it would break the interface of `std::pair`, since `std::pair` has members `first` and `second` which `tuple` does not. And a tuple of size one cannot have `second`... so it would create some annoying wrinkles that could be painful in metaprogramming I guess

Comment: @Columbo thanks for pointing this out. I looked into libc++ implementation and it is indeed interesting. I previously only looked into libstdc++ one and read about comparison between inheritance vs member approach.

Comment: Ok I see the point of allowing specializing `std::pair`. Then why not turn it around? Define `std::pair` properly, and alias `tuple<A,B> = pair<A,B>`, but tuples of other size `= tuple_impl<Ts...>` which is a "proper tuple". What problems would this incur? Like in this [second sketch](http://ideone.com/Ypnd23)

Comment: @leemes If you want a `pair`, declare your stuff as `pair`s. If you want to keep things more generic, you can't use `first` and `second` anyway. I.e. what purpose would all that serve?

Comment: @Columbo Because in my opinion having a distinct pair type is unnecessary (if no good reason exists). For example, let's say you write a library making heavy use of variadic templates and tuples, like some function returning a tuple. And let's say the number of elements in the tuple depends on the number of arguments of the function (similar to `make_tuple`). Maybe you now want that whenever he supplies 2 arguments, a pair comes out, so you would need to specialize it, since maybe 2 args is the most common case. Like with `std::map`s value_type, generalized to multiple dimenstions, what not...

Comment: @Columbo But basically, the main motivation which lead me to ask this question is the fact that it bothers me for years now. When I first heard about tuple back in 2009 or so, I was so sure that pair is just the same as tuple with two elements. I was so sure that I was quite baffled when I noticed it is not. It just felt so wrong. So very very wrong. And since then, I wonder what the problem is. I just want to know it now ;)

Comment: @leemes Your sketch completely fails to compile, in case you didn't notice. Anything along those lines would make template argument deduction from `tuple<Ts...>` impossible.

Comment: @T.C. That's why I wrote "Not to be meant to compile..." behind it, and called it sketch. But yeah, the deduction is a good point indeed.

Comment: Let's say, tuples supersede pairs. Pair is left for compatibility. Perhaps, the design was done such that deprecation of pair would not break users of tuple.

Comment: `std::pair` has already bean part of _C++98_, `std::tuple` (but without variadic templates) came with _TR1_. At that time it has not been possible to alias `tuple` with 2 elements to `pair` for several reasons. Template aliasing and variadic templates came with _C++11_. Even with this available you cannot coalesce `pair` with a specialization of `tuple` without breaking some existing code.

Comment: TR1's `tuple` and C++11's `tuple` have no requirement to be the same thing- that's the whole point of TR1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've gotta be careful about things like SFINAE and overloading. For example, the code below is currently well-formed but you would make it illegal:

```
void f(std::pair<int, int>);
void f(std::tuple<int, int>);
```

Currently, I can disambiguate between pair and tuple through overload resolution, SFINAE, template specialization, etc. These tools would all become incapable of telling them apart if you make them the same thing. This would break existing code.

There might have been an opportunity to introduce it as part of C++11, but there certainly isn't now.

Comment: This answer is the simplest to understand -- you explain how the compatibility would be broken if we changed it *now*. I guess it would have been possible to introduce a tuple in C++11 which was pair-compatible when having two elements (in the sense of how I described it).

Answer (score 2):

This is purely historical. `std::pair` exist since C++98 whereas tuple came after and was initially not part of the standard.

Backward compatibility is the biggest burden for C++ evolution, preventing some nice things to be done easily !

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this and don't have the bandwidth right now to do so. You could try making a specialisation of std::tuple, derived from a sd::pair. Someone please tell me this won't work or is particularly horrible idea. I suspect you'd run into trouble with accessors.

Comment: You're only allowed to specialize `std::` templates for your own classes, not in general.

Comment: If I can specialise my own classes, I can specialise std classes. I don't follow your reasoning. TBH I'm not sure it's terribly important, so won't be upset if you don't reply.

Comment: It's specifically banned by the standard. There's no reasoning involved. (There is a rationale; it would complicate the Standard Library implementation if you could).